# В TinyXML2 не получается считать файл с xml-разметкой

Tags: visual-c++, xmlparser

Здравствуйте. Имеется файл с xml-разметкой.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <connectionStrings />
....
</configuration>
```

С помощью данной функции определяем успешность выполнения функций. И почему-то не получается считать файл. Правильность пути к файлу проверена. Файл с xml-расширением давал - результат тот же.

```
bool Test()
{
    tinyxml2::XMLDocument xml_doc;
    tinyxml2::XMLError eResult = xml_doc.LoadFile("Web.config");
    std::cout << 1 << endl;
    if (eResult != tinyxml2::XML_SUCCESS) return false; // Здесь возникает ошибка чтения
    std::cout << 2 << endl;
    tinyxml2::XMLNode* root = xml_doc.FirstChild(); 
    if (root == nullptr) return false;
    std::cout << 3 << endl;
    tinyxml2::XMLElement* element = root->FirstChildElement("configuration");
    if (element == nullptr) return false; 
    return true;
}
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что я делаю не так и как мне это исправить?

Comment: Файл xml сохранён действительно в utf-8? Несоответствие кодировок - одна из самых распространённых проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснилось, что этому парсеру необходимо указывать полный путь файла

В итоге получаем

```
tinyxml2::XMLError eResult = xml_doc.LoadFile("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\adku.web\\Web.config");
```

По крайней мере после этого все заработало.